# Limit Image to size of containing view (xamarin.android)

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-imageview, android-gridlayout

I'm trying to create a chess board using a GridLayout in Xamarin.Android. Each View in the GridLayout will be an image view depicting a piece (if the square contains a piece). Before adding the image resource, the board displays fine. But as soon as an image is added, it pushes the size of the ImageView to be much larger than desired.

Here is the code I am using. The following method is run for each square on the board and creates the ImageView and returns it to be added to the GridLayout:

```
public View BuildSquare(Square squareModel)
    {
        SquareView rtn = new SquareView(this.Activity, squareModel); //SquareView extends ImageView
        rtn.UpdateBackgroundColor(); //set square color
        if (squareModel.Piece != null)
        {
            rtn.DrawPiece();
        }

        GridLayout.LayoutParams param = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();

        //set weight of each row and column to ensure equal size
        param.RowSpec = GridLayout.InvokeSpec(GridLayout.Undefined, 1f);
        param.ColumnSpec = GridLayout.InvokeSpec(GridLayout.Undefined, 1f);
        rtn.LayoutParameters = param;
        return rtn;
    }
```

and the DrawPiece() method is as follows, which sets the image resource:

```
 public void DrawPiece()
    {
        if (squareModel.Piece == null) return;

        string key = squareModel.Piece.GetPieceNotation();
        int resource = -1;

        //get the image resource corresponding to the piece on the ssquare
        if (AndroidConstants.PieceResources.TryGetValue(key, out resource))
        {
            this.SetImageResource(resource);
        }
        this.SetScaleType(ScaleType.FitXy);    

    }
```

When I comment out the rtn.DrawPiece() line, the board displays correctly as shown below:

[image]

However, when the line is included and the image resource is set, it displays as follows:

[image]

What you are seeing here is the top left square on the board hugely inflated to accommodate the image. I want the image to be scaled to fit in the square in the first image above. I have tried with different ScaleTypes but it seems to make no difference. Is this something to do with using the GridLayout? Or is there something else going on here that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to set the height and width to your `SquareView`.

For example:

```
        public View BuildSquare(Square squareModel)
        {
            SquareView rtn = new SquareView(this, squareModel); //SquareView extends ImageView
            rtn.UpdateBackgroundColor(); //set square color
            if (squareModel.Piece ==0)
            {
               rtn.DrawPiece();
            }

            //Set the height and width
            GridLayout.LayoutParams param = new GridLayout.LayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(50, 50));

            //set weight of each row and column to ensure equal size
            param.RowSpec = GridLayout.InvokeSpec(GridLayout.Undefined, 1f);
            param.ColumnSpec = GridLayout.InvokeSpec(GridLayout.Undefined, 1f);
            rtn.LayoutParameters = param;
            return rtn;
        }
```

And the result:

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you very much. I thought setting the size of the height and width would force it to be the specified size. But it seems the weighting on the GridLayout overrides this, which is exactly what I wanted.